# Manipulate NSDates in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I'm trying to manipulate a Date in Swift. What I'm trying to to is to set the hours, minutes and second of the actual Date to zero.

```
func getDate() -> (NSDate){
    let date: NSDate = NSDate()

    var components = NSDateComponents()
    components.setValue(0, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour);
    components.setValue(0, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute);
    components.setValue(0, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond);

    let expirationDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
    return expirationDate!
}
```

This is my code so war but it is not working. Any hints? 
The input would be "2015-07-30 18:31:08 +0000" the outpout schould be "2015-07-30 00:00:00 +0000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need (particularly the `components:fromDate:` call):

```
func getDate() -> NSDate {
    let date: NSDate = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    var components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date)

    return calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
}
```

This call will work on any iOS system after iOS 2.0 so compatibility shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It works but the result is also 2015-07-29 22:00:00 +0000 propably because of utc. I would like him to ignore the utc.

Comment: You'll simply need to set the `timeZone` property of the components to whatever `timeZone` you will using the date in.

Comment: Can this be done automatically? What somebody i australia uses my app. I allways want the result to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

there's a method of `NSCalendar` which does exactly what you're going to accomplish (10.9 and higher)

```
func getDate() -> NSDate {
  return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
}
```

to get the start of tomorrow, you could use this

```
let today = getDate()

let addOneDay = NSDateComponents()
addOneDay.day = 1
let tomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(addOneDay, toDate:today, options:NSCalendarOptions())!
```

Comment: works so far. But how can i get the start of the next day too? Also i think this is utc. my result is 2015-07-29 22:00:00 +0000

Comment: `NSCalendar` has a `timeZone` property. Set it to an appropriate value to adjust the time zone you need. The default value is the current time zone